# LInk from Oracle to TEXT FILE

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a text file that will be updated daily - I would like to log into my Oracle database, using SQL DEVELOPER only, and create some sort of LINK from the oracle database to the text file, so that other users of the oracle database (using it under this same schema permission) will be able to see it as a view or a table, and it will be the data inside the text file.

I am a relatively competent person in SQL Server etc., but I can't seem to find a way to do this - I've done a fair amount of reading, but it all seems to center around import/export.  I don't want to just import it.  I want a permanent link.

EDIT - Ok , I tried my best and came up with this - and the initial create table script works, but when I try to view Data in it, I get all kinds of errors. 
My first code is:

```
    CREATE TABLE AZ_MEDICAID_MBR_TEXT
    (MedicaidID VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
    MEMBERNBR VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    CURRELIGSTARTDATE NUMBER(*,0), 
    CURRELIGENDDATE NUMBER(*,0))
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY user_dir
     ACCESS PARAMETERS
       (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS (MedicaidID      VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
                MEMBERNBR         VARCHAR2(11 BYTE),
                CURRELIGSTARTDATE   NUMBER(*,0),
                CURRELIGENDDATE  NUMBER(*,0),
               )
       )
     LOCATION ('MedicaidMembers.txt')
    );
```

and the errors are:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found ")": expecting one of: "double-quoted-string, identifier, single-quoted-string"
KUP-01007: at line 6 column 16

ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "binary_double, binary_float, comma, char, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"
KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: VARCHAR2
KUP-01007: at line 2 column 33

ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "binary_double, binary_float, comma, char, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"
KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: VARCHAR2
KUP-01007: at line 2 column 33
```

Of course I can see an issue already - how exactly do I tell Oracle that the text file is pipe delimited with no text qualifiers?  I read the docs but I just don't grasp them.  I'm sorry - I really appreciate the help, I've done very little in Oracle other than query....

EDIT 8/17/2015:
boy it is really difficult on stack overflow to make replies and additional posts. all I can do is 'edit' my original post, I guess?...ugly.

I am now trying this:

```
    CREATE TABLE AZ_MEDICAID_MBR_TEXT
(MedicaidID VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
MEMBERNBR VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
CURRELIGSTARTDATE NUMBER(*,0), 
CURRELIGENDDATE NUMBER(*,0))

ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
DEFAULT DIRECTORY user_dir 
ACCESS PARAMETERS 
(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE FIELDS 
(
MedicaidID VARCHAR2(14 BYTE), 
MEMBERNBR VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
CURRELIGSTARTDATE NUMBER(,0), 
CURRELIGENDDATE NUMBER(,0)
)
) 
LOCATION ('MedicaidMembers.txt') );
```

And it creates the table, but then when I try to access the table, I get this error:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "binary_double, binary_float, comma, char, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"
KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: VARCHAR2
KUP-01007: at line 3 column 12
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a table with a `BFILE` column.  That assumes that the file in question is available on the database server's file system and that you can create an Oracle directory object that references that server-side directory.  http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/BFILE

Comment: Wow - I am not really an Oracle person, and I have wrestled with reading through the  Oracle docs before (they usually win after I am bloodied and bruised).  Let me give it a shot. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

External tables are another option. You will probably need a directory object set up for the folder you put them in also. Here's the link to Oracle's documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    field1 CHAR(10),
    field2 CHAR(30)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
        RECORDS DELIMTED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS
        (
            field1 CHAR(10),
            field2 CHAR(30)
        )
    )
    LOCATION ('/path/to/file.txt')
);
```

example for fixed width fields:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    field1 CHAR(10),
    field2 CHAR(30)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
        RECORDS DELIMTED BY NEWLINE
        (
            field1 POSITION(1:5),
            field2 POSITION(6:15)
        )
    )
    LOCATION ('/path/to/file.txt')
);
```

The syntax in the access parameters section should be the same as SQL Loader.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra comma at the end of your field list. I added an example for a fixed width file, is that what you meant by no text delimiters?

Comment: No text qualifiers means not having something like "apostrophes" around the value in a column.  Delimiters meaning something to delimit entire columns.. What I have will be a pipe delimited text file.

Comment: I edited my post to show my latest effort and error. I see what you meant about the comma, and it was removed in the latest effort. (the code to create the table works fine; accessing it is now the issue).